# Can't figure out this error near FROM statement in TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

This is probably a stupid mistake but I can't figure out what causes the error. I'm trying to compare the sum of Employee cost in one plan to the budget of the project before each insert. This is for sqlite, thanks for any answers in advance.

```
%%sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ins_PlanEmployees BEFORE INSERT ON PlanEmployees
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM Project pro
                INNER JOIN Plan ON pro.projectID = Plan.projectID
                INNER JOIN PlanEmployees ON Plan.pID = PlanEmployees.pID
                INNER JOIN Employee ON PlanEmployee.eID = Employee.eID
                WHERE SUM(cost) FROM Employee <= project.budget
            )
            THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'Over budget')
        END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query of

```
            SELECT 1
            FROM Project pro
            INNER JOIN Plan ON pro.projectID = Plan.projectID
            INNER JOIN PlanEmployees ON Plan.pID = PlanEmployees.pID
            INNER JOIN Employee ON PlanEmployee.eID = Employee.eID
            WHERE SUM(cost) FROM Employee <= project.budget
```

is syntactically incorrect because of the

```
WHERE SUM(cost) FROM Employee <= project.budget
```

part, because `SUM` is an aggregate function that does not evaluate to boolean and is incorrect by itself to form the where clause and the `FROM` cannot be defined twice, nor after the `WHERE`.

Possible fix:

```
            SELECT 1
            FROM Project pro
            INNER JOIN Plan ON pro.projectID = Plan.projectID
            INNER JOIN PlanEmployees ON Plan.pID = PlanEmployees.pID
            INNER JOIN Employee ON PlanEmployee.eID = Employee.eID
            WHERE SUM(cost) <= project.budget
```